# How to process the webservice xml message in mirth

Tags: mirth

How to process the webservice XML message in Mirth Connect 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct, you are asking for how to configure Mirth to become a Web server. It's actually easy and hard at the same time.

The easy way - create a new channel and configure the *Source* connector as *Web Service Listener*. Deploy the channel and you have a web server waiting for SOAP messages to be sent to a configured IP port. But the structure of these SOAP messages is governed by Mirth WSDL at localhost:8081/services/Mirth?wsdl.

If you want the SOAP message structure to be different then you are going to deep dive into creating your own Java class and overriding default web service methods. There is no a single answer for that, it is a completely separate topic.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are asking how to consume XML webservice message in Mirth?..

If you are receiving specifically SOAP you need to set webservice listener as your source channel listener. (as said previous answer, you will have the URL)

Go to your transformer and type the following code:

```
 logger.info(connectorMessage.getRawData());
```

Once you do this you can see the data you received inside Mirth on the logger area.